# Private and Shared Assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies

Can a strong named assembly (in GAC) access a private assembly (i.e. one which is not in GAC)?

By access I mean, may be using reflection invoke one of its method.

I have this doubt because I guess an assembly to be put in GAC is strong named because of security reasons. And referring an assembly outside GAC seems to me a security breach...Am I right? Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: are you talking about making internals visible to another library? see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why wouldn't that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using reflection it is possible. If is not in the GAC you will need the file path to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

The only difference that being in the GAC makes is that any program can load your assembly without needing to locate it.